Can $10^m+10^n+10^p+1$ be a Perfect Square Number?
I have trouble proving if $10^m + 10^n+10^p+1$ can be a square number for $m>n,>p\geq 1$ integers.
I have tried some modulos against $8$ and $9$ and other prime number, because $10^m + 10^n+10^p+1$ can be 1 (mod 8) when $p \geq 3$ and $10^m + 10^n+10^p+1$ always be 4 (mod 9), and $10^m + 10^n+10^p+1$ can be 4 (mod q) for any prime number $q \geq 7$, which can't give me the conclusion $10^m + 10^n+10^p+1$ will be a square number or not.
For example, $1049^2=1100401$, very close to $10^m + 10^n+10^p+1$, so I think it will take more research to prove this problem.

There are many squares of this form, if we allow $n=p$. This admittedly silly observation means that any argument needs to have a step, where $n>p$ is crucial. Modulo any integer we can find occasions when $10^n\equiv 10^p$ even though $n>p$. So congruences alone won't do.
